# Find image path and view using PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have a form application in which I can input a name of an image and view the image in a `PictureBox` after clicking a button.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string image = textBox1.Text + ".jpg";
    PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = image;    
}
```

This is my code but it doesn't do anything, the image I tried to search didn't appear in the `PictureBox`. What could possibly go wrong? Answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've created a new instance of `PictureBox` but you didn't add it to your form. You should add it to your form's controls like this:

```
string image = textBox1.Text + ".jpg";
PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
//Set pictureBox1's location on the form
pictureBox1.Location = new Point(10 , 10);
//Add pictureBox1 to your form
Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
```

Now if your `image` variable contains a valid image path your `PictureBox` should show it.

**Edit:** To write a valid image path in your `TextBox` try write the full picture's path in your `TextBox` like below:

```
D:\Pics\yourPic
```

Or if you've added it to your project it should be like this:

```
D:\New folder (1)\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\yourPic
```

Just don't forget if you have already placed a `PictureBox` in your form  you just need to call it in the code. You don't need to create a new one. And you should remove this line `PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();`.

Comment: in my form i have already placed a picturebox. do i still need to do that? @s.akbari

Comment: @KentAbrio...So you just need to call it in the code. You don't need to create a new one. Remove this line `PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();`

Comment: Yep thanks. already did everything. but a small X button appears not the image. what is wrong this time?

Comment: @KentAbrio...This is because your image path is invalid. You should set the `pictureBox1.ImageLocation` to a valid path.

Comment: @KentAbrio...Did you add the pictures to your project? Can you show what are you typing in your `TextBox` ?